# template type dependecy and inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a template method defined as

```
template<class T>
const std::list<T>& GetList()
{
  return GetList(std::shared_ptr<Parent>(new T()));
}

const std::list<std::shared_ptr<Parent>>& GetList(const std::shared_ptr<Parent>&a)
{
    //
}
```

Given that `T` is type of classes that take Parent as a parent class, e.g

```
class Child1:public Parent
{};
```

Compilation error :
`Can not convert const std::list<std::shared_ptr<Parent>>& to  const std::list<T>&`

Is there any way to fix this without changing the type of `T` into a shared_ptr ?

Comment: A list of shared_ptr of T is a different thing from a list of T. It's not just a case of type mismatch. What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I have a defined method 
`const std::list<std::shared_ptr<Parent>>& GetList(const std::shared_ptr<Parent>&a)
{
    //
}`

Now I need to write a template to make use of it but it should return a list of T which are subtypes of Parent

Comment: And what becomes of the shared pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

The definitions have to match.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Parent> ParentPtr;

std::list<ParentPtr> GetParentList(const ParentPtr& a)
{
    //
}

template<class Child>
std::list<ParentPtr> GetParentListT()
{
    ParentPtr parent_ptr(new Child);
    return GetList(parent_ptr);
}

...
std::list<ParentPtr> my_list = GetParentListT<Child1>();
```

Also make sure that `Child1` is defined (and not merely declared) prior to using this code, otherwise the compiler won't know that it's a subclass of `Parent`.